# MongoDB - unique string field constraint

Tags: mongodb, nosql, unique

I have been searching for some hours how to make the ISBN field unique and haven't found a solution. Creating an index gives me the following error. I still didn't understand how these indexes work - I am in the process of learning. If you come with a quick solution let me know!

Attempt to create an index

```
db.books.createIndex( {ISBN : 1} , {unqiue : true} )
```

Error

```
/* 1 */
{
    "ok" : 0.0,
    "errmsg" : "Error in specification { key: { ISBN: 1.0 }, name: \"ISBN_1\", unqiue: true } :: caused by :: The field 'unqiue' is not valid for an index specification. Specification: { key: { ISBN: 1.0 }, name: \"ISBN_1\", unqiue: true }",
    "code" : 197,
    "codeName" : "InvalidIndexSpecificationOption"
}
```

Schema

```
db.createCollection("books", {
  validator: {
    $jsonSchema: {
      bsonType: "object",
      required: [
        "ISBN",
        "title"
      ],
      properties: {
        _id: {},
        ISBN: {
          bsonType: "string",
          // make this unique
        },
        title: {
          bsonType: "string",
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: You misspelled `unique` when you attempted to create an idnex.

Comment: yep, this was the problem - thanks!